# Mono System.Argument Exception in Mac when using System.Drawing.Font

Tags: c#, .net, macos, fonts, mono

Im trying to create a new font from the system font in C#(Mono).

```
 System.Drawing.Font myfont=System.Drawing.SystemFonts.DefaultFont
```

The code works properly in Windows but when it comes to running in Mac i get an argument exception-`The Requested font family Could not be found`

I thought that the default font may be missing,So i tried with Helvtica.That is installed On Mac by default

```
  System.Drawing.Font myfont=new System.Drawing.Font("Helvetica",10f);
```

Still the same exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [SystemFonts.cs](https://github.com/mosa/Mono-Class-Libraries/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/SystemFonts.cs), the Default Font is Microsoft Sans Serif size 8.25.

The exception you mention is thrown from [gdipFunctions.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/a31c107f59298053e4ff17fd09b2fa617b75c1ba/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/gdipFunctions.cs), which means you are mostly likely using the Mono 2.0 or a similar older branch of Mono which is using the GDI based implementation of the FontFamilies rather than the CoreText implementation.

Do you have xquartz installed and what is the output of fontconfig , the relevant bug report is [FontFamilyNotFound exception from bundled Xamarin.Mac app on OS X 10.7](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12576), which recommends upgrading to versions of Mono which are 3.0.12 or newer.

In summary either upgrade your version of Mono or, install xquartz and ensure fontconfig configuration as part of FreeType is able to detect the font you want to use as per the comments in [the release notes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cocoa-sharp-dev/S-VMikAa1EU).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear answer,Let me check after updating to Mono 3.0.12,i think i have 2.0 version installed on Mac.My Home PC internet connection is down right now let me check and get back.

Comment: I just updated Mono to 3.0 and now the code runs perfectly.No Exceptions are thrown.Do you think using GDI+ for drawing in Mono is a bad idea?

Comment: It isn't a bad idea, it just needs fontconfig to be configured correctly and xquartz to be installed.

Comment: I plan to combine the Mono Run-time Environment with my application.I don't want to ask the user to install stuff separately.Will there be any issues with that?

Comment: Not using the newer version of Mono. If you using the older version you will need to combine xquartz as well, and have an automated script that ensures fontconfig configuration is correct